# Flutter: Access File from specified location

Tags: flutter, flutter-file

As question explains itself the problem,

Below code is used to access the file, but it's returning false, but the file exists on a particular location

```
          Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
          String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
          File file = File('${appDocPath}/folder_name/out.mp4');
          bool value = await file.exists();
          print(value); // return false
```

How could I get the right access of file here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before reading  any file first we need to give access to storage permssion.

**Add Storage Permission**

```
permission_handler: ^5.0.1 // in pubspec.yaml file
```

**Get Access at Runtime of storage permission**

```
   var status = await Permission.storage.status;
      if (status.isUndetermined) {
        // You can request multiple permissions at once.
        Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
          Permission.storage,
        ].request();
        print(statuses[Permission.storage]); // this must show permission granted. 
      }
```

**Finally, Call**

```
      File file = File('/storage/emulated/0/folder_name/out.mp4');
      bool value = await file.exists();
      print(value); // return false
```